# How can total charge be plus or minus?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge

I am a grade 10 student and in our syllabus we have electricity chapter. In the chapter the formula to measure the total charge of a body is:

$Q=±ne \tag{1}$

Where Q is the total charge, $n$ is the number of electrons in the body and $e$ is the charge possessed by 1 electron.

$e = -1.6 \times 10^{-19} \, \rm C$

The textbook says that we use ± symbol in the formula to indicate that the charge can be negative as well as positive.

But my doubt is that if we are measuring charge on the basis of the number of electrons, then it should always be negative, right? Because electrons have negative charge. If a body has 10 electrons, then it will have $e = -1.6 \times 10^{-19} \, \rm C$ of charge. It should always be negative.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. This definition is a little confusing. What "bodies" are we talking about? No objects only consist of electrons, but also contains protons, meaning their total charge is not the number of electrons, but the difference between number of protons and electrons.

Comment: According to the textbook, the "bodies" refer to the conductor.

Comment: Here's an example: https://www.vedantu.com/iit-jee/basic-properties-of-electric-charge. They have not mentioned the ± symbol. But I have seen it at several places.

Comment: Have you asked your teacher for help?

Comment: Yes, he told that "the charge can be taken out too". I was a bit confused with his explanation. That's why I came to stackexchange.

Comment: @MeetShah. As your teacher told you, charge, for example electrons, can be added to or taken out from the material or conductor. Another common way of charging an object is by add into it positively or negatively charged ions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

surely the body will include sources of positive charge as Koschi suggests, such as the protons in the nuclei of the atoms that form the conductor. In this sense, one of the atoms that form the "conductor object" with a lack of electrons may be interpreted as a source of positive charge to the body. This would be a very simple picture for that interpretation:

$Q_{object}=\sum_{i}^{\text{all the atoms}}Q_{i}$

and for each atom:

$Q_{i}=(n_{protons}-n_{electrons})\times |e|$

where $e$ is the charge of an electron.

Hope it helps, and sorry in case there is some confusing point in my comment!

Answer (score -1):

Just to clarify, even though $e$ is commonly said to be “the charge of a single electron” it is actually defined as [“the charge of a single proton” or "the **magnitude** of the charge of a single electron"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge) instead, and is therefore positive with one electron having $-e$ charge;

Now, answering to your question, equation (1) refers to the total charge that results from removing ($+$) or adding ($-$) $n$ electrons to the material. An uncharged material has the same number of protons and electrons; a negatively or positively charged material has being given or removed $n$ electrons respectively. A related concept are [ions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion#Anions_and_cations).

Comment: I accidentally down voted and for some reason couldn't correct